# Pulling ID from one collection to another using common parameter

Tags: angular, mongodb, angular8

Okay so I'm fairly new to angular, and my applicants collection references the job postings collection with ID,

but how do I pull the postTitle using the applicant.post parameter which matches the id parameter of the posts collection?

both schemas

Post

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  category : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
  id: String,
  postTitle: String,
  postAuthor: String,
  postDescription: String,
  postQualifications: String,
  postReference: String,
  updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

Applicant

```
var ApplicantSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    post : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' },
    id: String,
    appName: String,
    appPhone: String,
    appEmail: String,
    appAddress1: String,
    appAddress2: String,
    appResume: String,
    updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="button-row">
        <a mat-flat-button color="primary" [routerLink]="['/applicant']">Back</a>
      </div>
      <hr>
    <div class="row application">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>{{applicant.appName}}</h3> 
            <h4>Applying for: {{applicant.post}} || Need post.postTitle </h4>
            <h4>Submitted: {{applicant.updated | date: 'dd MMM yyyy'}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <h4>{{applicant.appPhone}}</h4>
            <h4>{{applicant.appEmail}}</h4>
            <h4>{{applicant.appAddress1}}, </h4>
            <h4>{{applicant.appAddress2}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <a class="btn btn-block" button (click)="deleteApplicant(applicant.id)">
                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
            </a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p innerHTML={{applicant.appResume}}></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to make changes in your node.js application, use mongoose population and populate Post model in your router file where you're filtering applicant based on the id, something like this:-

```
Applicant.findOne({id: req.applicant.id})
.populate('post')
.then(res => {// postTitle will be accessible here})
```

here Applicant is your model.

Refer [mongoose populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Comment: So where would I add it on here? I tried adding and I'm only getting error messages

Comment: `router.get('/:id', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), function (req, res, next) {
  var token = getToken(req.headers);
  if (token) {
    Applicant.findById(req.params.id, function (err, applicant) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(applicant);
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(403).send({ success: false, msg: 'Unauthorized.' });
  }
});`